# log in failure by typing correct username and password

Tags: login

after Reboot,
login screen came then typing correct username and password then also login failed
only black screen come and same login again this thing repeating.

Comment: what are you trying to log into?

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: did it work before reboot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.